# Version control software for ASP (classic)?

Tags: version-control, asp-classic

Is there any version control software out there for ASP Classic?

(Please no discussions about the choice of ASP- its not my decision)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

ASP classic files are just plain text files.
So you don't need any special VCS software, you can use anything which can deal with plain text files (which means, **really** anything).

For example:

- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)